# stopping a rig bone from bending

Tags: rigging

how to stop bone from bending when using IK bone. it is not shown in the picture but i have limit location and limit rotation set to 0 on the bone that i want to stop bending to see which one could fix it but unfortunately it didn't. I would like to keep two bones in the forearm. I have been looking around for solutions but not finding fix for my issue.
[image: help with unwanted bending]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a bone from getting rotated by an IK chain it's taking part in, lock the axes of the bone in properties/bone/inverse kinematics:

[image]

Constraints like limit rotation will not prevent IK from rotating a bone.  All constraints are evaluated before IK.  So the limit rotation will only limit the rotation going into the IK solver, which will then be free to rotate the bone *after* that rotation has been limited.

Unless you axis lock it, which tells the IK it can't rotate that bone in any locked axes.

Comment: thank you very much for quick response and it is a solution so i will mark it as a solution but i forgot to add to my original question that i would like the ability to twist that bone abit. from my understanding on the answer you gave is that i wont be able to twist.

Comment: If you want to twist it, don't lock Y, or make it non-deforming, with a deforming child that doesn't take part in the IK.

Comment: thank you very much. been scratching my head for 4 days with this. still learning a few things on rigging.